# How to show form registration only before user registers.

Tags: android, registration, launch

**WHAT I HAVE**: My apk have due task. 
The registration of an account and the main menu of my apk.

**WHAT I WANT**: The first time you launch the application, the form of registration must be shown. After the user completes the registration (checked with a server), will launch the application menu. (So the next times the form registration won't launch anymore.)

**PROBLEM**: How i can do this? Can someone show me how to do?Some tutorials or some snippets code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to [store](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) info, wheather user has already registered or not not. depending on this show registration or go straight to main menu.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "PrefLogFile";
public static final String PREF_REGISTERED = "registered";
final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // sets righr preferences

    boolean registered = pref.getBoolean(PREF_REGISTERED, false);
    if (registered) {
        //go to main menu here
    }else{
     //do registration here


   //after registration is complete do this:       
   pref.edit().putBoolean(PREF_REGISTERED, true).commit();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use Share Preference  for this purpose. use this in oncreat() method of your form registration like this

```
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub!!
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        SharedPreferences versionfile  = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
         boolean  isRegister =versionfile.getString("Registration",false);
         if(isRegister){
                 setContentView(R.id.yourRegistrationlayout)
         }else
                      //Start menu Activity

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). These preferences is save to use for this purpose.

```
class MainMenu extends Activity {
  protected static final String PREFS_USER = "user";

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart(); //don't forget this, because you must call parent onStart method
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_FILE, 0);
    String userKey = prefs.getString("userKey", null );

    //if user key is not set yet, you should open registration Activity
    if (userKey == null) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Registration.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
```

O use onStart method, because you need recheck user registration after complete it.

Then user success register, you can set users key whit this code:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences( PREFS_FILE, 0);
prefs.edit().putString("userKey", userKey ).commit();
```

In addition, you can combine with [startActivityforResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities)

some additional reference and explanation can be founded [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState).